# Is this correct approach for a single summation in time domain in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a single summation of a function in the time domain. I got my code working, but I would feel more confident if someone would verify the correctness or point out my mistakes.

Here is a picture of the formula I am trying to code:

[image]

And here is the code itself:

```
h = 100;
t=[1:400];
rho_w = 1025;
g = 9.81;
Ohm = [0.01:0.01:4]
Phase = rand(1,length(Ohm))*2*pi;
Amp = [1:1:400];

for i = 1:length(t)
    P(i) = rho_w*g*sum(Amp.*Ohm.*cos(Ohm*t(i)+Phase))
end
```

Comment: FYI, the square brackets (`[ ... ]`)you use are superfluous and only make the code harder to read. They're only needed if you're concatenating two or more entities, e.g., `[1:400 500:10:600]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's correct (thanks to @horchler for his valuable comment).

You can also do it with `bsxfun`:

```
P = rho_w*g*sum( bsxfun(@times, (Amp.*Ohm).', ...
    cos(bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@times, Ohm.', t), Phase.'))) );
```

Comment: That would assume that the time is distinct from the n values of `Ohm` and `Phase`. It may just be a coincidence that they have the same number of elements.

Comment: @horchler Good point. In the equation `t` doesn't have a subindex `n`.

Comment: Clearly the `for` loop is a lot simpler and might even be faster than all of that!